# Impact of calling layoutIfNeeded without calling setNeedsLayout for a view?

Tags: uiview

Can we call layoutIfNeeded if we are not calling setNeedsLayout .

```
  [self.contentView setNeedsLayout];
  [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
```

Is there any benefit of calling layoutIfNeeded, if developer is not calling setNeedsLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly. Changes you make to views that impact auto layout will get picked up at the next drawing cycle. However there might be cases where you want those changes to take effect immediately, say, because you want to use the new position to calculate geometry for other views. In those cases, call `layoutIfNeeded` immediately after your changes.

Be aware that calling `layoutIfNeeded` a bunch of times between drawing cycles can affect performance so only use it when actually needed.